# Given two circles, prove the following

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBmy5.png)

I was able to identify the cyclic quadrilateral that exists, but not sure how to prove this using that information

Comment: $\angle QPA=\angle ABS=\angle SRm$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There's not just one, but two, cyclic quadrilaterals. Draw the line $AB$.

Answer (score 0):

$\angle QPA=\pi-\angle ABQ=\angle ABS=\pi-\angle ARS=>PQ \;||\;RS\\\text{Q.E.D.}$